# How to capture piped command error message

Tags: linux, shell, scripting

I am trying to capture ERROR message if the command failed in any of the pipe OR IF the command success its output in variable.

```
k=$(ls | pl) 
pl: command not found
```

I have tried this below also but not able to store error message

```
$ k=$(ls | pl) > out 2>&1
pl: command not found
$ cat out
```

Still out file is empty. is there any way i can achieve this.

Comment: Consider that syntax then k=$(ls|pl 2>out.txt) . Redirecting StdErr outside of the parenthesis redirect the errors from the assignation.

Comment: it didn't worked in this case: k=ls | pl | grep lol 2>&1

Comment: k=$(ls 2>>out.txt| pl 2>>out.txt|grep lol 2>>out.txt) that works

Answer (score 1):

Just re-direct like this:

```
$ erroe=`ls | pl 2>&1`
mayankp@mayank:~$ echo $erroe
pl: command not found
```